# Docker compose - image not found

Tags: docker-compose

I'm following http://bradgessler.com/articles/docker-bundler. The first time around, it made "bundler fast again". I started getting issues with some missing linked files in the gems, so I blew away the docker images, and did a `docker-compose build`. After it built, I could no longer do `docker-compose run web bundle` -- I get this:

```
Creating network "myapp_default" with the default driver
Pulling bundle (myapp_web:latest)...
Pulling repository docker.io/library/myapp_web
ERROR: Error: image library/myapp_web:latest not found
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the same article, here are the steps that worked for me:

1. Run `docker-compose build web`
2. Find the name of your web image: run `docker images`. Mine was 'appcontainer_web'
3. Open `docker-compose.yml` and replace *'image: myapp_web'* with *'image: [your_image_name]'*
4. After the above change I still encountered an *error: No closing quotation*. The fix was to remove the quote from *"I'm"* in that same `docker-compose.yml` file *"command: echo I'm a little..."*